# PHP how to keep the matched item's key with array_search and array_column?

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

How can I keep the matched item's key with `array_search` and `array_column`?

```
$items = array(
    'meta-title' => [
        "code" => 'meta-title'
    ],

    'meta-keywords' => [
        "code" => 'meta-keywords'
    ],
);

$key = array_search('meta-title', array_column($items, 'code'));
var_dump($key); // 0
```

The result I am after:

```
'meta-title'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry my mistake. check my edit above. thanks.

Comment: How about you split it to multiple statements and use `in_array` instead? 1. get all columns 2. use `in_array` to check if the column is there 3. if `true` - you know the column name.

Comment: how would u do it with that?

Comment: I have explained the "algorithm"

Comment: thanks for the idea. let me try.

Answer (score 1):

Your `array_columns()` call returns a numerically indexed array of strings (based on the keys from the 1st level), not the array that you're wanting to search (i.e. an array of the 'code' values from the 2nd level).  You might be better off iterating through `$items` and building an array (key/value pairs) based on searching the arrays you're iterating through:

```
$items = array(
    'meta-title' => [
        'code' => 'meta-title'
    ],

    'meta-keywords' => [
        'code' => 'meta-keywords'
    ],
);

$results = array();
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    $result = array_search('meta-title', $value);
    if ($result !== false) {
        array_push($results, array($key => $result));
    }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71934db55c67657f0336f84744e05097d00eda6d

Answer (score 1):

Here is an object oriented approach that allows the column and search value to be set at run time.  As a class it's more reusable and somewhat self documenting.

```
<?php
$items = array(
    'meta-title' => [
        "code" => 'meta-title'
    ],

    'meta-keywords' => [
        "code" => 'meta-keywords'
    ],
);


/** 
 * Search all records of a recordset style array for a column containing a value
 * Capture the row into matches member for later use.  
 */
class ColumnSearch {

    private $key; 
    private $search;

    public $matches=array(); 

    public function __construct( $key, $search ){
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->search = $search;
    }

    public function search( array $items ){
        // @todo validate $items is like a recordset
        $matches = array_filter( $items, array( $this, "_filter"), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );
        $this->matches = $matches; 
        return count($matches); 
    }

    private function _filter( $row, $rowKey ){ 
        return ( $row[$this->key] == $this->search ); 
    }
}

$search = new ColumnSearch( 'code', 'meta-title' ); 

$occurances = $search->search( $items ); 

// return value indicates how many were found, in case of multiples...
echo $occurances ." ". PHP_EOL;

// the matched row will be in matches member.  
var_dump($search->matches); 

// there might be more than 1, not in your example but this is very generic code.
// grab just the keys, then get the current 
echo current( array_keys($search->matches) ) . PHP_EOL;

echo "New Search for value that doesn't exist.". PHP_EOL; 
$newSearch = new ColumnSearch( 'code', 'title' ); 
$count = $newSearch->search( $items ); 
if( 0 == $count ){
    echo "Nothing found.". PHP_EOL; 
}
echo current( array_keys( $newSearch->matches) );
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83b306bfc30ef2a055cf49501bdeb5cb2e5b5ed7